# Retrieving first name and last name from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How can i echo the first and last name of the specific user that logs in?
Here is my code for checkLogin.php:

```
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM myweekprofiles WHERE LastName='$LastName' and FirstName='$FirstName'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("FirstName"); 
session_register("LastName"); 
header("location:loginSuccess.php");
}else {
  //This page will describe that the email/password is incorrect
}
```

Here is the code for inc_header_User.php:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])) {
echo "Hello";
}else{
$FirstName = $_SESSION['FirstName'];
}
```

I try to echo $FirstName within the header, but i get an error that says:

Undefined variable: FirstName in C:\wamp\www\MyWeek\includes\inc_header_User.php on line 55

Comment: could you please point which line is line #55?

Comment: First off. You'll likely get a response to 'NOT USE MYSQL_* FUNCTIONS'. They are a bit outdated. mysqli is a better solution, or possibly PDO. As for this question, do you have `session_start();` in your page code before trying to call `$_SESSION['Firstname']`?

Comment: line #55 says <?echo $FirstName;?>

Comment: Also, as a heads up, you will want to do some research on 'SQL Injection' and how to combat it before beginning with any kind of login system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Just as an FYI, per the PHP site: _"`session_register` - This function has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 5.3.0 and **REMOVED** as of PHP 5.4.0."_ For the best portability among systems, and to protect your code from breaking if you ever decide to upgrade, you consider using `$_SESSION` instead.

Comment: You also need to call `session_start();` before adding anything to the session variable, and you may need to call `session_write_close();` at the end of the script.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler good catch I missed in my answer, too many things, luckily there're also many eyes here (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that could have gone wrong.

**First**, `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.` from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php). So delete these lines from checkLogin.php:

> <strike>session_register("FirstName");</strike>
>
> session_register("LastName");

And write this instead (note the added [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) ):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['FirstName'] = $FirstName;
$_SESSION['LastName'] = $LastName;
```

**Second** (might be derived from the first, might not be), the logic in inc_header_User.php could be wrong for your purposes, try changing it to:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])) {
$FirstName = '';
echo "Hello";
}else{
$FirstName = $_SESSION['FirstName'];
}
```

**Other notes:**
Is it an error, a notice or a warning? It doesn't look fatal actually, echoing a non-set variable will not likely kill your whole app.

You are prone to MySQL injection, change the first lines to this:

```
$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
```

As already suggested, try using MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql_* functions for new code.

Comment: Is this better:                                if(!isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])) {
  echo "Hello";
}else{
  $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $FirstName;
}
?>

Comment: I edited the answer since I found another logic mistake that is causing the actual error. If the session variable is not set, you keep it unset, which causes the problem. And I don't think that new code you wrote is better...

Comment: You might add as well, that the session should be started ;)

Comment: I added the code you included:                                          if(!isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])) {
$FirstName = '';
echo "Hello";
}else{
$FirstName = $_SESSION['FirstName'];
}                                                                                       but i still dont see the firstname appering

Comment: Does it work better now? I re-edited now for fixing another small bug Michael Wheeler and budwiser catched that I didn't

Comment: Now it looks like a perfect answer.

Comment: Thank to you for pointing it out, I missed it (; Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: It still is echoing "hello". I included everything, but no name appears.

Comment: If i include a session start above the if statement, i get an error stating that a session has already started. The other session start was defined within checkLogin.php

Comment: Do `var_dump($_SESSION);` after the line `session_start();` in inc_header_User.php and add what it says before 'hello' at the end of your question, please. If it says array(empty) or similar, add the same line before `header("location:loginSuccess.php");` at checkLogin.php please.

Comment: Okay, then you don't need that one (it was just another thing to check just in case).

Comment: when i include var_dump($SESSION) i get an error that says:              A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()                     array (size=2)
  'Email' => string 'testemail' (length=9)
  'Password' => string 'tyler' (length=5)

Comment: Then, as you can see, you don't have the FirstName saved in the $_SESSION. Run it in the other place I specified, please, and post again.

Comment: if i use this code:                                                                             f(!isset($_SESSION['Email'])) {
$FirstName = '';
echo "Hello";
}else{
$Email = $_SESSION['Email'];
echo $Email;
}                                                                                   The email is displayed for the correct user that logged in.

Comment: I think you are getting lost here... that should be clear from the code you just posted in the comment: the email and password are being saved in the global SESSION variable, but the FirstName and LastName are not, which is what you want to retrieve. Therefore, there's some error somewhere in the script that you are using to save them (probably `checkLogin.php`), did you edit in your code the modifications of my answer? Also, I highly encourage you to completely read some [PHP SESSION tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) to get things straight about how SESSION works.